# Get checked radio button value from multiple form lists

Tags: jquery, forms

I have the following code which is working fine in getting the values from the checked radio buttons. I then tried adding more than one section of radio buttons but every time i run the code it adds text to every text input.

I believe i need to use .each somewhere in this codee but cant seem to figure out where.

My code is in the following jsfiddle if anyone would be kind enough to take a look.

The Radio Fields

```
<div class="dropdown">

   <input type="text" class="it" value="">
   <input type="radio" name="hey" value="one">
   <input type="radio" name="hey" value="two">
   <input type="radio" name="hey" value="three">

</div>

<div class="dropdown">

   <input type="text" class="it" value="">
   <input type="radio" name="hey" value="one">
   <input type="radio" name="hey" value="two">
   <input type="radio" name="hey" value="three">

</div>
```

The Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("div.dropdown").each(function () {
      $("input[type=radio]").click(function(){
         $(".it").val(this.value);
      }); 
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
// binding the anonymous function of the on() method
// as the change event-handler:
$('input[type=radio]').on('change', function () {

    // caching the changed radio-input:
    var changed = this;

    // starting to traverse from that changed radio input:
    $(changed)
        // traversing to the closest ancestor element with
        // the class of 'dropdown':
        .closest('.dropdown')
        // looking within that element for an <input>
        // element with a 'type' attribute equal to 'text':
        .find('input[type=text]')
        // setting the value of that <input> to be equal
        // to the value of the cached radio input:
        .val(changed.value);
});
```

```js
$('input[type=radio]').on('change', function() {
  var changed = this;

  $(changed)
    .closest('.dropdown')
    .find('input[type=text]')
    .val(changed.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown">

  <input type="text" class="it" value="">
  <input type="radio" name="group1" value="one">
  <input type="radio" name="group1" value="two">
  <input type="radio" name="group1" value="three">

</div>

<div class="dropdown">

  <input type="text" class="it" value="">
  <input type="radio" name="group2" value="one">
  <input type="radio" name="group2" value="two">
  <input type="radio" name="group2" value="three">

</div>
```

Note that I also changed the `name` attributes of each group, in order for them to *act* as separate groups.

References:

- [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
- [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

Answer (score 0):

I assume,

- Your click function execute when you select a value from radio button.
- You want to update your text value which under the same div as your radio button

Then you can try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("input[type=radio]").click(function(){
     $(this).closest("div.dropdown").find(".it").val(this.value);
  }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is pretty close--you just need to change the selector so that it only changes the input prior to the radio.  Lots of different ways to do that.  Here is one.

Also, I've removed the `.each` iteration as it is quite irrelevant.  The click handler was being registered twice, in exactly the same way, because you were registering it in an iteration through both DIVs.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("input[type=radio]").click(function(){
         $(this).prevAll(".it").val(this.value);
      }); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation - that helped a great deal in understanding where I was going wrong.